# Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03005e

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am Getting this Error when running the code in lower version Android Mobile. Please Help me how to solve this Issue. i search for this issue but i did not found the exact where am i doing mistake.

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03005e
End of managed Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException stack trace ---
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03005e
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1125)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2316)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:941)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at md5ec747b7423972841ddca33efeffb70b8.LoginActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
at md5ec747b7423972841ddca33efeffb70b8.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:32)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
In mgmain JNI_OnLoad
```

Here is my code

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);
        getUser();
        //play background video
        //videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.BackVideo);

        IP_Address = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.IPAddress_Text);
        Username_IV = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.UserName);
        Password_IV = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Password);
        Remember = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.Rembember);
        login = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Login);
        //speech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        IP_Address.Text = "192.168.x.xxx/Sample";
        login.Click += login_Click;
        //login_Click();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.Indeterminate = true;
        dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
        dialog.SetMessage("Authenticating...");


    }
  async void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            HideKeyBoard();
        dialog.Show();

        var p = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //speech.Speak("Authenticating", QueueMode.Flush, p);
        if (IP_Address.Text.Length <= 0)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Please Enter IP Address", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            IP_Address.Focusable = true;
            //speech.Speak("Please Enter Password", QueueMode.Flush, p);
            dialog.Dismiss();
            return;
        }
        if (Username_IV.Text.Length <= 0)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Please Enter UserName", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Username_IV.Focusable = true;
            //speech.Speak("Please Enter UserName", QueueMode.Flush, p);
            dialog.Dismiss();
            return;
        }
         if (Password_IV.Text.Length <= 0)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Please Enter Password", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Password_IV.Focusable = true;
            //speech.Speak("Please Enter Password", QueueMode.Flush, p);
            dialog.Dismiss();
            return;
        }           
        else
        {

            IPAddress = IP_Address.Text.Trim();
            string API = "http://" + IPAddress + "/api/Sample/LoginCheck?username=" + Username_IV.Text + "&password=" + this.Encrypt(Password_IV.Text) + "";
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            string dataResult = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(API);
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataResult))
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Login Success", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                //speech.Speak("Log in Success", QueueMode.Flush,p);                   
                dialog.Dismiss();
                rememberMe();
                StartActivity(typeof(HomeActivity));
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Login failed", ToastLength.Long).Show();

                //speech.Speak("Log in Failed Please Check Your Credentials", QueueMode.Flush, p);
                dialog.Dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Login failed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            dialog.Dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: post you code here.

Comment: I Posted My code.

Comment: I am getting that exception in this line SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);

Comment: I've set the target android version to Android 4.4, no such issue occur by my side, can you please try to clean the entire solution and rebuild it?

Comment: It is working fine after enabling the 'Use Fast Deployment' Checkbox in the Project Properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of changes need to do . I have replaced your code with some of the changes and also do other changes according to you. Like ids of UI should be correct.

```
@override 
protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
        // Create your application here
        setContentView(R.layout.Login);
        getUser();
        //play background video
        //videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.BackVideo);

        IP_Address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.IPAddress_Text);
        Also edit other UI componenets Like this.
}
```

Comment: Why like that both are not same ? can you please explain.

Comment: Yes, It is Working in android 5.0 perfectly. Not working in 4.4 version.

Comment: SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);